# Angular router navigate skipLocationChange doesn't work on subsequent attempt using resolver

Tags: angular

I have a case where I use a resolver and if there is an error I redirect to an error page but I would like the url to not change to the error components address.

Using the router's skipLocationChange property it works on the first attempt. On subsequent attempts it changes the url to the error page.

My question is how can I setup a solution with the router so that when I route to the error page it doesn't change the address bar url?

I've setup a simple example here:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hx6rgm

- Steps to reproduce

  - Go to the example page
  - Click on "GoTo Component Test"
  - Notice you get "component-error works!"

    - However the address bar url does not change
  - Click on "GoTo Component Test" again

    - This time the address bar url changes

The example project is pretty simple there is a "TestResolver" that simply navigates: (each time you click GoTo Component Test)

```
this.router.navigate(['component-error'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

Comment: Why would you route to your error-page from your error-page since your solution seems to work when routing from any component to your error-page?

Comment: The routing actually doesn't happen directly from the error page, it happens from the resolver, however you can run into a case where from the error page you go to a different component and that component has a resolver and then that resolver can potentially get an error and go back to the error page.

Comment: So it can seem like it is going from the error-page -> error-page, however it is error-page -> component-test (resolver causes an error) -> error-page.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have found a workaround solution on this. Since while resolver blocks user to direct to the page, navigation process should be suspended until the resolver returns resolve or reject. As an example, imagine you want to route to a page when user clicks a button;

```
<button (click)="onNavigation()" ></button>
```

In the component and controller function:

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-error',
  templateUrl: './error.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error.component.scss'],
})
export class ErrorComponent {
...

  constructor(private router:Router){}

  private isRouting:boolean = false;

  onNavigation(){
     if(this.isRouting === false){
        this.isRouting= true;
        this.router.navigate(['component-error'], { skipLocationChange: true }).finally(() => this.isRouting= false);
     }
   }

}
```

By doing this way you guarantee 2 important things:

1. Your url location doesn't change as expected.
2. If you make asynchronous get & fetch calls in your **resolver**, you don't call them more than necessary.